# Xcode and AppleDeveloper ID differs

Tags: ios, xcode

I have different team ID in Xcode and Apple Developer. To solve this, I've installed provision, but getting the error:

[image]

I've clicked manage certificates, added Developer certificate but it was signed with a wrong ID, not with one that is in developer account.

[image]

How can this be solved? Also, does it somehow influence on sending push notifications, if I generate an APNS certificate based on bundleID, which is equal?

Comment: Several things: are you sure you entered the correct development team? This might cause a mismatch if you have the correct provisioning profiles installed but not the certificate of the given team. That can happen when your AppleID is part of multiple development teams or when you checked out a project of another team.
So: make sure you have the certificate of the selected team installed. Or change the team in the project settings to your own.

Comment: @JanBrinker Yes, the development team is selected correctly. 
So: make sure you have the certificate of the selected team installed. How can I check this?

Comment: Also, iOS distrubution and iOS developer certificates have different iD's in keychain

Comment: Log in to the developer portal and then on the top right you can select the team for which you want to do things. Select the team you have set in your project settings. Then navigate to the certificates and download your certificate. I think there's probably also a way to do this with Xcode, but I usually manage my certificates with fastlane match or use the portal.

Comment: @JanBrinker I've downloaded certificate from DeveloperPortal and it has the same Id as in Xcode, bu not as in top right corner of portal. How can I create developer certificate with ID like in portal?
https://monosnap.com/file/QxFMLCSjiJjCFxgvHKFtoc60dHKBp8

Comment: If you chose the correct team in the top right and then downloaded the certificate, then you downloaded it for that specific team, not another one. You're currently trying to sign the app with one identity (certificate) from another team than is set in the project file. So you need to get that certificate. Also make sure you download the development certificate if you want to develog/debug and not the distribution one. You can only use the distribution certificate for uploading to the AppStore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194686/discussion-between-drevival-and-janbrinker).